# Cordova - Android - Why is the WebSQL and Local Storage data being deleted by the Android OS?

Tags: android, cordova, local-storage, hybrid-mobile-app, web-sql

I have an app called Fudget (which is a Cordova app for Android & iOS) which uses WebSQL to store the user's app data locally. This has worked ok for years (I occasionally had an Android user whose data would be wiped by the Android OS - but not often).

But in the last couple of days, 100's of Android users are having their WebSQL (and Local Storage) data removed by the Android OS - so I'm getting a lot of angry emails from people who've lost all their data and settings.

Can anybody tell me why this is suddenly happening? What has changed recently in the Android OS to cause this? And is there any way I can stop this from happening?

Comment: Prognosis on that bug report doesn't look very positive. They are treating it as a P0 but the proposed fixes seem to have complications. Good luck on your end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The newest Chromium `WebView` update causes this due to the following bug:

- [Issue 1033655: localstorage or websql unexpectedly cleared](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1033655&q=component%3AMobile%3EWebView&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified)

Here is a related news post:

- [Some Android apps suffer data loss after latest Chrome/WebView update](https://ww.9to5google.com/2019/12/14/android-apps-data-loss/)

Comment: Thanks so much Richard, that's super helpful . At least now I can tell users it's out of my hands 